# I want image to be displayed inside nav bar when hovered on

Tags: css

I want image to be displayed inside nav bar (rectangle bar) when hovered on. I have added a div element inside anchor tag and the used that div class in css to dispay when the element is hover. but right now when i try with below code, its not happening the way i want

HTML CODE:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="#" class="home"><img src="images/home.png" alt="" class="hidden-xs"><span class="visible-xs">Home</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#/create">
                        <div class="play">
                            <img src="images/Picture13.png" />
                        </div>
                        <img src="images/add-128.png" style="height:20px; width:20px;" /> Create Application
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

CSS Code:

```
.navbar{
    padding: 8px 0;
}
.navbar-nav > li{
    margin-right: 12px;
}
.navbar-nav > li > a,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a{
    background-color: #bcd6ed;
    border: 1px solid #bebebe;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 16px;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
    background-color: #fff;
    background-image: url('../images/Picture13.png');
    border-top: 2px solid #003052;
    border-right: 2px solid #003052;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #003052;
    border-left: 10px solid #003052;
    color: #003052;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a:hover .play{
    display: block;
}
.play{
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    top: 0%; 
    width: 40px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    left: 0px;
    right: 100px;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

Comment: Can you host the images so they're pulled through so we can get an idea of dimensions and such?


Edit: Update links in this Fiddle too, then we can help more https://jsfiddle.net/pa70tq34/

Comment: I think more importantly than the image dimensions is what you mean by "the way you want." What is it exactly what you're trying to achieve. Thanks :)